# Correct way to handle redirect after async call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need, if some condition meets, make ajax call to server to update data. My function looks like following:

```
function doSomething() {
    if (something) {
        callSomethingAsync()
    }

    window.location = "/redirecturl"
}
```

My question is, is it always guaranteed that callSomethingAsync will be finished before redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is being executed line by line. If it only consisted of synchronous operations, it would be guaranteed that the redirect happens after any code before is done processing.

However, as `callSomethingAsync` is an async call, you cannot expect it to be always finished before the `window.location` fires.

If you'd want to make sure of it, you'd include the redirect line as the last step of the `callSomethingAsync` function, or you'd extend the function to take a callback.

Answer (score 1):

If your async call returns a promise, then you can just `await` for it. Only when the ajax call is completed and a response is returned as a promise then only next line of codes will execute (which can include redirects also) like:

```js
// This is a async call, can be a ajax call inside promise
// we are using setTimeout with 2s delay 
function getCoffee() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // It takes 2 seconds to make coffee
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Got the ☕ after 2s'), 2000);
  });
}

// Added async to this function
async function doSomething() {
  console.log('Making coffee first');
  const coffee = await getCoffee();

  // This log will only show after async call has finished
  console.log(coffee);

  // or something like redirect
  // window.location = "/redirecturl"
}

doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic html starting page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Stack Overflow Test Redirect</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Js part with JQuery:

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/test/', 
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true, 
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); } 
});
```

and Vanilla JS example:

```
function makeRequest (method, url, done) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
//   xhr.withCredentials = true; <--CORS ENABLED!
  xhr.onload = function () {
    done(null, xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    done(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
}

// And we'd call it as such:

makeRequest('GET', '/test.com/', function (err, datums) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log(datums);
});
```

Beware CORS.
Hope it helps..