# Redirect from async function in react?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have a function being called when a form is submitted which is like so:

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";

export default (async function submitSite(values) {
  console.log(values);
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: values
  })
});
```

After this function is done, how can I redirect to another page. I have tried using `this.props.history.push` and `window.location.replace()` after the api call but neither works.

**Update**

```
export default (async function submitSite(values) {

  try {
    await this.createSite({
      content: values
    });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  createSite(site) {
    return API.post("notes", "/notes", {
      body: site
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: You can set a state in the component that holds your form like `submitted: false` and when you get a response from your API you change the state to true and in your render function do something like this.state.submitted ? <Redirect to="/submitted" /> : <Form />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect in routes after async request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976758/how-to-redirect-in-routes-after-async-request)

Answer (score 0):

When using an async function you can use [await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to wait for the promise to be resolved. You can then redirect using for example this.props.history.push('/path').

Comment: If the linked documentation is not helpful you could try and see if the following is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487535/correct-way-to-handle-redirect-after-async-call

This might help as an example for await. You could also use .then(). That would work in the following way:

submitSite(values).then(result => doSomethingElse(result))
or
submitSite(values).then(this.props.history.push('/path'))

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: I have updated the question with my updated attempt

Comment: Are you using the return value of API.post for anything? Are you getting a specific error? 

I can only do very limited tests myself right now, but this works for example for me: 

async function submitSite(x) {
 try {
  await createSite(x);
    print('this.props.history.push("/")')
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
  
  function createSite(site){
    print(site)
  }
}

submitSite('site_example')

Comment: No, do I have to use the return value?

Comment: No just curious

Comment: Ah right, I used this example because It was in a tutorial I was previously referencing. Also in the example you gave, their is no reference to the API.post call? 

I really appreciate you helping btw

Comment: Yes I was trying to simplify it using print statements (because I dont have the actual functions you are calling), srry. Are there any error messages when you run your code?

Maybe try: 
export default (async function submitSite(values) {

  try {
    await createSite({
      content: values
    });
    this.props.history.push("/");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  function createSite(site) {
    return API.post("notes", "/notes", {
      body: site
    });
  };
});

Comment: I get an alert saying "cannot read property of props undefined"